# ASP.NET Checking all form elements if all of text values empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, .net

I have a repeater that lists the result of the search process. After search users will be able to update some data but before update i want to check all form elements (including dropdownlists and textboxes) if user does not enter or select any data. If all of them are empty i assign 0 to check value. Here is my implementation but i'am getting this error

```
System.InvalidCastException
```

in marked line

```
            int check = 0;
            foreach (RepeaterItem itemm in searchResultRepeater.Items)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < itemm.Controls.Count; i++)
                {
                    Control ctrl = itemm.Controls[i];
                    if (ctrl is TextBox || ctrl is DropDownList)
                    {
                        TextBox tb = (TextBox)ctrl;
                        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)ctrl;
                        if ((tb.Text != null && tb.Text.Length > 0) || (ddl.Text != null && ddl.Text.Length > 0))
                        {
                            check = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

How can fix this ? Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "as" instead of the hard cast.  If using as then you don't need the is because if it can't cast it will be null.

```
int check = 0;
foreach (RepeaterItem itemm in searchResultRepeater.Items)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < itemm.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        Control ctrl = itemm.Controls[i];
        // use as to safely cast will be null if can't convert
        var tb = ctrl as TextBox;
        var ddl = ctrl as DropDownList;

        if ((tb != null && tb.Text != null && tb.Text.Length > 0) ||
            (ddl != null && ddl.Text != null && ddl.Text.Length > 0))
        {
            check = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use Linq if you just want a bool.  Both textbox and dropdownlist implement the interface ITextControl.  This will return true or false not 1 or 0.

```
var check = searchResultRepeater.Items.OfType<RepeaterItem>()
                                .SelectMany(c => c.Controls.OfType<ITextControl>())
                                .Any(c => (c is TextBox || c is DropDownList) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text));
```

Comment: I'am getting System.NullReferenceException inside of the if statement this time.

Comment: Fixed.  Need to check the object isn't null as well

Comment: Same exception again.

Comment: What is the exact exception?  I can't recreate with my mocked up test.  The check for tb != null and ddl != null seems to work.

Comment: It was null reference exception

Comment: I don't know why you would get the null exception.  I've also added a Linq example maybe that would work better for you.

Comment: Tartar - does your repeater have a HeaderTemplate and/or a FooterTemplate ? That might explain the null reference exception; the code above assumes all items are ItemTemplate/AlternatingItemTemplate

Comment: I have only item template.